# How to add push notification for Android app which uses Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: android, push-notification, amazon-dynamodb

My Android app uses data from Amazon DynamoDB. I want to add "push notification" for my app. That means when new data is added to DynamoDB, our app will receive a notification. I didn't find the tutorial for push notification with DynamoDB. Please help me!

Comment: instead of GCM check out https://aws.amazon.com/sns/ its push notification from amazon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplished this task in 3 different ways

1. Store your Notification token in DynamoDB table on inserting an item in table send notification from server side
2. As suggested in comment you can use service of SNS that will help you to send notification to the user
3. Configure a Lambda function which can be integrated with DynamoDB table easily, on insert item you can write a code which will send notification

Edit: You have to choose two options (node.js, java) while using lambda. When you configure a lambda function it will ask for DynamoDB table and the event you want(in your case adding row/item). In this lambda function you have to write a custom code to send the notification.

Comment: I'm a beginner with DynamoDB and Lambda. Could you please describe more clearly about the 3th way? How can Lambda function send notification to users?